# how to zip multiples files in java , so that when we unzip , it should not be in folder

Tags: java, file, zip, unzip

There are 3 files which I want to zip.

I am able to zip these files using the below code

```
public class TestZip {
public void zipFiles(List<String> files){

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("NeoloadProject/New folder/testing.zip");
        zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
        for(String filePath:files){
            File input = new File(filePath);
            fis = new FileInputStream(input);
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(input.getName());
            System.out.println("Zipping the file: "+input.getName());
            zipOut.putNextEntry(ze);
            byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
            int size = 0;
            while((size = fis.read(tmp)) != -1){
                zipOut.write(tmp, 0, size);
            }
            zipOut.flush();
            fis.close();
        }
        zipOut.close();
        System.out.println("Done... Zipped the files...");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try{
            if(fos != null) fos.close();
        } catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
public static void main(String a[]){

    TestZip mfe = new TestZip();
    List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    files.add("NeoloadProject/New folder/repository.xml");
    files.add("NeoloadProject/New folder/scenario.xml");
    files.add("NeoloadProject/New folder/settings.xml");
    mfe.zipFiles(files);
}
```

}

So the output of the program is testing.zip
So when I unzip , all my files are in testing folder.
testing folder --> file1, file2 , file3

My requirement is that when I unzip this zip file it should directly zip , without any folder wrapped on it.

Comment: What does `files` contain?

Comment: i want to zip 3 files (.text), into a single zip file.
When i unzip the file it should not wrap all my files into a folder 
example: testing.zip to testing folder and then all the files in it 
it should be unzipped outside directly with all the files.

Comment: I hate when people respond to a question by ignoring it and repeating themselves.

Comment: Are you unzipping the files in a Java program, or through a command line, or a GUI?  If command line, what operating system?  Command line options may be in order.   If GUI, which one?

Comment: through java program